# How to solve nonlinear reaction-diffusion PDE using implicit finite difference method?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, finite-difference-methods

I want to solve a reaction-diffusion PDE, for example
$$
\frac{\partial s}{\partial t} = D\frac{\partial^2s}{\partial x^2}+Ks^2+f(x), x, t\in[0,1]\\
s(0,t)=s(1,t)=s(x,0)=0
$$
where $s$ is a function of both $x$ and $t$. First I tried explicit finite difference method but this does not ensure stability and causes a problem. Therefore, I want to apply implicit method. For example, backward Euler method applied to a uniform grid gives
$$
\frac{s^{n+1}_i-s^n_i}{\Delta t} = D\frac{s^{n+1}_{i+1}-2s^{n+1}_i+s^{n+1}_{i-1}}{(\Delta x)^2} + K(s^{n+1}_i)^2 + f(x_i)
$$
where superscript denotes time $t=t_n$, subscript denotes space $x=x_i$. 
If there is no nonlinear term $(s^{n+1}_i)^2$, I can solve this by matrix inversion. However, this nonlinear term cause trouble. Also, there are two unknowns $s_{i+1}^{n+1}$ and $s_i^{n+1}$, so Newton's method is not applicable. What is the best way to solve this?

Comment: $\dot s=Ks^2$ explodes all on its own, as its solution is $s(t)=\frac{s(0)}{1-Ks(0)t}$. You can not expect that the solution with dissipation and the $f$ term is much more stable. The numerical solution can not be better than that if it has some degree of accuracy. // If you are using an implicit method, why not go directly to the trapezoidal one, with the space discretization it is also called Crank-Nicolson, the effort is the same, the order in $t$-direction one higher.

Comment: @Dr.LutzLehmann Yes, I want to use Crank-Nicolson exactly, but still the term $\frac{1}{2}((s_i^{n+1})^2+(s_i^n)^2)$ bother me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One typical idea is to apply Newton's method or a Newton-like method. Essentially, you put all terms that are linear in the next state $s^{n+1}$ on the left side, and add some additional term to (locally) compensate for the non-linear terms.
$$
s^{n+1}_i-D\frac{Δt}{(Δx)^2}(s^{n+1}_{i+1}-2s^{n+1}_i+s^{n+1}_{i-1})-2KΔt(a_is^{n+1}_i)=s^n_i+Δt\Bigl(K(s^{n+1}_i-a_i)^2 - Ka_i^2+ f(x_i)\Bigr)
$$
Applying the inverse linear matrix of the left side to this system results in a fixed-point equation $s^{n+1}=G(s^{n+1})$. One easy choice is to fill the $a_i$ with the previous values of $s^{n+1}_i$, which removes the first term of the right side. This would give the usual Newton method where the linear system changes in each step. One could also keep the $a_i$, and thus the matrix and its factorization, constant. The $a_i$ would be filled with the initial value for the $s^{n+1}_i$, obtained via Euler step or extrapolation, or even set to $a_i=s^n_i$. This will all converge with different speeds, slower in each variant, but each still faster than the naive fixed-point iteration 
$$
s^{n+1}_i=G_i(s^{n+1})=s^n_i+D\frac{Δt}{(Δx)^2}(s^{n+1}_{i+1}-2s^{n+1}_i+s^{n+1}_{i-1})+Δt\Bigl(K(s^{n+1}_i)^2 + f(x_i)\Bigr).
$$

Comment: Thank you! You mean apply fixed point theorem to the whole set of the equations for $i$ and $n$? Or apply to each small system
$$
A[s_{i-1}^{n+1}, s_i^{n+1}, s_{i-1}^{n+1}]^T = G?
$$

Comment: Oh I got it. So we first equate all the equations to get a matrix inverse, then use fixed point theorem! What I'm stuck is 
1)Why we need to add $a_i$? Can you give me a reference for the convergence? 
2)Also, is there a criterion for choosing initial values of $s_i^{n+1}$? I would like to set all $s_i^{n+1}=1$ if it doesn't matter!

Comment: You have, as a solution of a differential equation, $s^{n+1}_i=s^n_i+O(Δt)$, so it is a sensible choice to start with $a_i=s^{n+1}_i=s^n_i$. The usual theorems for the convergence of the Newton or simplified Newton method apply, that is, you get local convergence. You should get that when $Δt$ is small enough so that the matrix is contractive, then the error in the equation reduces by a factor $(Δt)^2$ in each fixed-point iteration step. // When comparing with an exact solution remember that making $Δt$ smaller does not reduce the error from the space discretization.